# css styles in Magento are always loaded in body

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I load style files into the title of the page. Then I do it:

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
```

But in this case in head i see only `<meta>`. All styles and js - loaded in end of body. Any ideas?

Comment: check your layouts and find where meta is loading, check all references to  before_body_end block

Comment: It's interesting that if you stop the script immediately after the 

`<head>
<? php echo $ this-> getChildHtml ('head')?>
</ head>
<?php die; ?>
` 

 then everything will load in `head`

Comment: There's probably a module / something in your theme that is loading it at the end of the body. What's wrong with loading it there ? It's probably better to load render blocking js/css at the bottom.

Comment: I need to first load the styles, because if the styles are not in the head - the page loads terribly ugly

Comment: Well if that's the case check your footer.phtml in your theme and see if <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?> is being called. If so then that will overwrite that first call in the head.